# How do I add a drop shadow to a Chart.js v4 graph?

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to create a graph in Chart.js v4.4.0 that has a drop shadow under the plot line like Flot.js used to make.

Among StackOverflow, YouTube, and the Chart.js GitHub page, I've found a number of posts surrounding the general concept.  Unfortunately, nearly all posters fail to include the version of Chart.js their proposed solution is intended to apply to, but the long story short is that I haven't been able to make any of them work in Chart.js 4.4.0, with most error messages indicating some sort of namespacing or API problem.  Doubly unfortunately, the Chart.js documentation is so severely lacking that I can't resolve these on my own.

If anyone wants more detail on the approaches I've tried and how they failed, I would be happy to supply more details.  I've been working at this one problem for six weeks, though, so the list of attempts and failures is too long to post here.

Several of the approaches almost work, in that they create lines with shadows.  However, they create shadows under *everything*: the grid axes, lines, legend, etc.  I don't want that.

How can I create drop shadows under **ONLY** the line of a scatter plot on a Chart.js 4.4.0 plot?

**UPDATE**

At a commenter's request, this is the code for my attempt to add shadows following the strategy of extending the Line element:

```
class lineWithShadow extends Chart.controllers.line {
  draw() {
    const ctx = this._ctx;
    ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(39, 127, 254, 1)";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
    super.draw();
  }
}

lineWithShadow.id = 'lineWithShadow';
Chart.register(lineWithShadow);

/* Create the Chart.js chart */
let cjs_plot = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'lineWithShadow',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: histogram,
      borderWidth: 1.2,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    showLine: true,
    pointStyle: false,
    borderColor: 'rgba(255,204,0,1)', 
    borderWidth: 1,
    fill: '+1',
    scales: {
      y: {beginAtZero: true}
    },
  }
});
```

The result of trying this is that the data on the chart collapses to a single vertical line at the left edge of the chart.  There are no errors in the console.  This effect might be because I'm using scatter data, not line data.  If I change `Chart.controllers.line` to `Chart.controllers.scatter` in the first line of the above, the graph data returns to normal, but there are no shadows under the plot line.

Comment: Can you provide source code for how you are creating graph and configuring options ?

Comment: @Saidamir I've tried probably a dozen different ways over the last six weeks, too much code to post at once.  If there's a specific strategy you think will work, I'm glad to post whatever I've done that's related to that.

Comment: @karel Yes, I've included the code and its results as an edit to the question.